# "Accumulating" scalaz-stream channel

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

I'm trying to implement a scalaz-stream channel that accumulates statistics about the events it receives and, once complete, emits the final statistics.

To give a concrete, simplified example: imagine that you have a `Process[Task, String]` where each string is a word. I'd like to have a `Channel[Task, String, (String, Int)]` that, when applied to that initial process, would drain it, count the number of times each word occurs, and emit that.

I realise this is trivial through a fold:

```
input.foldMap(w => Map(w -> 1))
     .flatMap(m => Process.emitAll(m.toSeq))
     .maximumBy(_._2)
```

What I'm trying to write is a collection of standard accumulators that I can then just pipe my processes through - rather than explicitly fold, say, I'd write:

```
input.through(wordFrequency)
     .maximumBy(_._2)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss though - I can't work out how to do so without sharing state. Writing a `Sink` that accumulate to a `Map[String, Int]` is fairly simple, but there's no way to get the final state of the map and emit it once the sink has terminated.